# bind 'indent-to-column' to C-tab

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I'm trying to bind `indent-to-column 100` to <kbd>C-TAB</kbd> (or even just `indent-to-column` so I could then enter the column number I want), but what I tried isn't working:

This gives me an error when I open emacs:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>") 'indent-to-column 100)
```

This seems to have no effect:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>") 'indent-to-column)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second expression should work (in that it should bind `indent-to-column` to <kbd>C-TAB</kbd>, but you still have to provide the argument). You can check this using the following key sequence to see what <kbd>C-TAB</kbd> is bound to:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>C-TAB</kbd>

---

If you want to provide the argument as well, you can use this kind of construct:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>")
                (lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (indent-to-column 100)))
```

Comment: Thanks Francesco, with or without the 100: the <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>C-TAB</kbd> just gives me information regarding <kbd>TAB</kbd> - it doesn't seem to recognize the <kbd>C-</kbd> part

Comment: Are you using Emacs in "no-window" mode (i.e. within a terminal)? If so, which terminal? Otherwise, which system are you running Emacs in? It looks like the `C-TAB` key event is not passed correctly to Emacs by the underlying environment...

Comment: I am using emacs from a terminal on mac os x (10.8.3), running bash...  I switched to using `M-TAB` and that is working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(global-set-key [(control tab)] 'indent-to-column)
```